# how i can plot a graph with inetger number as input

Tags: matlab, graph

how i can plot `cos(3 pi/7 * n )` such that n be integer number in interval [x=0,x=10] in matlab?
i used this code

```
figure
X = linspace(0,2*pi,10)';
Y = cos(X);
stem(X,Y)
set(gca,'xlim',[0,10])
```

the graph that i get is this , but i want to show points of graph in integer number of x axis . how can i do that ?

[image]

Comment: Most plotting functions let you drop the `X` input variable, and it will plot `Y` as a function of `1:length(Y)`.

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html): `stem(Y) plots the data sequence, Y, as stems that extend from a baseline along the x-axis. The data values are indicated by circles terminating each stem. If Y is a vector, then the x-axis scale ranges from 1 to length(Y).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using linspace for such a simple example as this one, you can just define your vector `X` as an integer vector taking steps of `1`, from `0` to `10`:

```
figure
X = 0:1:10;
Y = cos(3*pi/7*X);
stem(X,Y)
set(gca,'xlim',[0,10])
```

Below shows the plot generated by the code snippet above (bottom plot) as well as the same plot using step size `0.5` (`X = 0:0.5:10`, top plot).

Note that as Adriaan notes in the comments below, the default step size for `... = from:stepsize:to` notation is `1`, i.e., if omitting the `stepsize` and simply writing `... = from:to`, a step size of `1` is used by default (`stepsize=1`).

[image]